# Going from MySQL to MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I recently have started coding PHP again and I have noticed that the function MySQL is now deprecated and I can either use PDO or MySQLi. Well I've been using this script http://evolt.org/PHP-Login-System-with-Admin-Features/ and I am very confused. I moved everything from `MySQL_` to `MySQLi_` and I now have this errors:

> Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in     C:\wamp\www\website\include\database.php on line 25

And here is my code

```
$this->connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die(mysqli_error());
mysqli_select_db(DB_NAME, $this->connection) or die(mysqli_error());
```

I don't see anything wrong with my code either, very confusing...

Comment: where are you declaring / defining DB_NAME ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You switched parameters of `mysqli_select_db` function, see the [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php).

First has to be `mysqli link`, second DB name.

```
mysqli_select_db($this->connection, DB_NAME);
```

In Mysqli you can pass `DB_NAME` directly in `mysqli_connect` as a fourth parameter too.

```
mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
```

Comment: Right but why do we have to mix procedural style with OO?

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky: it isn't fault, is it? Sure, it isn't _ideal_, nothing more. I've just used the style set in question and fixed there an error with parameters.

Comment: It is a fault, they will loose their job when their team lead finds that out. And their code will be error prone too. Your answer is right but you don't have to use the mistakes they made cause you know much more than the OP does and any good advice from you will be helpful for them in the future. 2 cents you know :)